# Is it possible to get platform or suite names found in .kitchen.yml inside a recipe?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, test-kitchen

.kitchen.yml:

```
platforms:
 - name: win2012r2

suites:
  - name: example
```

Is it possible to get the running platform or suite name from within a recipe? I've tried `node['platform']` and `node['suite']` but both are empty.

Comment: I think this is possible through the use of ohai: https://docs.chef.io/ohai.html . If you install ohai as part of your converge then I think you can use the `node['platform']` like you wanted to.  Also look at this: https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/kitchen-ohai

Comment: @Liam thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately with kitchen-ohai `node['platform']` evaluates to `windows` rather than the `.kitchen.yml` platform name.

Answer (score 0):

`node['name']` evaluates to the suite name plus platform name joined by a hyphen (e.g. `example-win2012r2`).

Answer (score 0):

you can use [ohai](https://docs.chef.io/ohai.html):

> Ohai is a tool that is used to collect system configuration data, which is provided to the chef-client for use within cookbooks.

you can have ohai load as a part of the [ohai cookbook](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/ohai) and then leverage it to retrieve the desired information. such as

```
node['platform']
node['platform_family']
node['kernel']['os']
```

Comment: As I mentioned to @Liam above, that returns a generic platform name (e.g. "windows"). I'm interested in the specific name given in .kitchen.yml